How to optimize java code using the features of java 8
The code below works fine but I want to optimize it and write it in another way.
private List<OrderFeedback> getControlOrderFeedback(List<OrderInner> orderInners){
    List<OrderFeedback> controlResult = new ArrayList();
    if(isTypeDeclaration){
        orderInners.forEach(co -> {
            controlResult.add(OrderFeedback.builder()
                    .result(co.getResult())
                    .code(co.getCode).build()
            );
        });
        return controlResult;
    }
    return null;
}


What exactly do you mean by "optimize it"? Without a clear metric for "optimization", the question is unclear. Also: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Ervin Knuth: Computer Programming as an Art (1974), p. 671

Note that OPs choice of word was "improve", which is even less clear.

Also, it's already using features of Java 8.

@MarkRotteveel yes, I know. Is there another way to optomize it

That is impossible to answer without more context.

Not sure what is the bottleneck here but you can rewrite it in a more java-streams fashion like
private List<OrderFeedback> getControlOrderFeedback(List<OrderInner> orderInners){
    if(!isTypeDeclaration) {
        return null;
    }
    return orderInners.stream()
               .map(co -> OrderFeedback.builder().result(OrderInner::getResult).code(OrderInner::getCode).build())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

Note that the only benefit here is that it won't create new ArrayList() unless it passes the isTypeDeclaration check.

I believe you still need co.getResult() and co.getCode(). Anyway a nice reduction in the number of lines.
